# Dolphin crashes regularly and Computer freezes

Tags: freeze, crash, kubuntu

my problem is, that my Linux Kubuntu 17.04 crashes from time to time:
The mouse get stuck, all app freezing and the fan speeds up.

I thought it is because the RAM usage is too high and Swap is full, so I googled and found users with the same problem which they fixed by set limits to keep some RAM free to let the system operate correctly.

Unfortunately this did not work.

Did had anyone the same problem and managed to solve id?
Here is my crash report:

```
Application: Dolphin (dolphin), signal: Segmentation fault
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fbea3a42900 (LWP 4312))]

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fbe7b0fc700 (LWP 4415)):
#0  0x00007fbea32cf951 in __GI___poll (fds=0x7fbe740029e0, nfds=1, timeout=-1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:29
#1  0x00007fbe9653a169 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fbe9653a27c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fbe9d51c49b in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007fbe9d4c1e3a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fbe9d2e13ca in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007fbe9d2e629d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007fbe986477fc in start_thread (arg=0x7fbe7b0fc700) at pthread_create.c:465
#8  0x00007fbea32dbb5f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fbe89c57700 (LWP 4342)):
#0  0x00007fbe9d51c393 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#1  0x00007fbe965396a8 in g_main_context_prepare () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007fbe9653a09b in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007fbe9653a27c in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007fbe9d51c49b in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007fbe9d4c1e3a in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007fbe9d2e13ca in QThread::exec() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007fbe9d998e45 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5
#8  0x00007fbe9d2e629d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#9  0x00007fbe986477fc in start_thread (arg=0x7fbe89c57700) at pthread_create.c:465
#10 0x00007fbea32dbb5f in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fbea3a42900 (LWP 4312)):
[KCrash Handler]
#6  0x00007fbea35f5d2d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so
#7  0x00007fbea35ff051 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so
#8  0x00007fbea3600fc6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so
#9  0x00007fbea0b55cd8 in KMainWindow::readPropertiesInternal(KConfig*, int) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5XmlGui.so.5
#10 0x00007fbea0b55d22 in KMainWindow::restore(int, bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5XmlGui.so.5
#11 0x00007fbea3604dfa in kdemain () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_dolphin.so
#12 0x00007fbea31e81c1 in __libc_start_main (main=0x56009c491730, argc=3, argv=0x7ffedb718118, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7ffedb718108) at ../csu/libc-start.c:308
#13 0x000056009c49176a in _start ()
```